# I have a lot of partitions in my laptop and I don't know where to install Linux

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, partition

I want to have both Linux and Windows in my laptop and I wanted to create a partition to install Linux there. The thing is, when I go to the **Disk Management** section, there are already a lot of partitions. I don't understand why and I don't which should I use to install Linux?

[image: My current partitions]

It can probably be a dumb question but I really know nothing about it so some help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

so you can use one of  partition but into your consideration  the minimum capacity should be up to 10 GB
for more information you can check:
http://dailylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside_8.html

Answer (score 0):

Disk 0: 2,6,7,8,9 are all blank, I'd recombine them by 'extend' in diskpart.

In order:

```
Diskpart/List volume/Select volume ''/ Extend
```

Then create a ext2 partition from those (if you are doing Unbuntu) and install Linux on that. Use the wizard in Diskpart (easier than command line) I believe I used a 20GB partition for mine.

If you dont want to do all that, just reformat partition 9. It should be big enough for most OS's.

Of course drive type and size will depend on the flavor of Linux used, so check their documentation.

Who knows why those partitions are there, someone may have created them at some point for whatever reason. But they are empty so most likely a mistake (if its a work or refurb computer other users may have done it and you just never noticed till now)...but that is all speculation.

Also, here is a link for the format process in case I missed something: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17418/windows-7-create-format-hard-disk-partition